# Webfocus report server issue

Tags: webfocus

I am working in webfocus support and totally new to it.I need to know where we can see the list of data services agent running in administration Console.Can anyone please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

For a server admin account, the list of active agents for all users is shown in the Management Center under Server Workspaces. Individual users can manage their own agents using the 'Manage My Agents' option in the dropdown list from the Tools icon near the upper right of the browser window.

Reporting Server Workspaces

[image: 1]